# Formula in table header cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a table in *Excel 2007* that I want to summarise, in a similar fashion to a Pivot Table, but for various reasons I can't use a pivot table.

I like the "Format as table" features of sort and filter buttons, automatic formatting etc, so have used that to create a simple table:

```
         A            B            C                    N 
   +-----------+------------+------------+-------+------------+
 1 |           | 01/01/2010 | 01/02/2010 |  ...  | 01/12/2010 |
   +-----------+------------+------------+-------+------------+
 2 | CategoryA |     15     |     545    |       |    634     |
 3 | CategoryB |     32     |     332    |       |    231     |
 4 | CategoryC |      5     |     234    |       |    644     |
   |    ...    |            |            |       |            |
27 | CategoryZ |      2     |     123    |       |     64     |
   +-----------+------------+------------+-------+------------+
```

The numbers are retrieved from a "back-end" pivot table using `GETPIVOTDATA()`.

All that works fine.

Now, the problem is that I can't seem to use formulas for my column headings in these new "smart" tables - they are converted to text or just broken.

For example if in **B1** I put `NOW()`, I don't get the date, I get `00/01/1900`.

Is there any way of getting a formula to work in the auto tables?  Or do I have to use standard tables and manually alternate-colour my rows etc?

Comment: I think its static text only for the headers. You could use VB to overwrite the headers though.

Answer (score 6):

It is only static text for headers because they are `named fields` and therefore can be referenced. If they were dynamic, it would wreak havoc with formulas using them as references.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Excel 2010, but this may work in 2007.  If you turn off the Header Row in the Table Design, you should be able use a formula in the row above your table data.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Table, Convert to Range it should keep the colouration of alternate rows but still allow formulae in the column headings.